# Remote into machine using local account when you don't remember the PC name?

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to remote into a computer using the local Administrator account on that machine, however I don't remember what the name of the computer is. Is there a way to specify that I want to use the local Admin account without knowing that info when typing the login creds into Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

**.\Username** is the username format you would use in this scenario.

Comment: When I try that, it doesn't use the name of the host computer but fills it in with the name of my own computer. Now maybe there's a misunderstanding on my part, and this is effectively the same, but I'm assuming that by doing this it's looking for a domain of the name of my computer. Is that incorrect?